# FileSystemWatcher. Как получить оригинальное имя файла?

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте!

Изменения в директории отслеживаются с помощью класса FileSystemWatcher.
Как получить оригинальный путь скопированного в эту папку файла?
То есть узнать откуда был скопирован файл.

Приведенный ниже код (e.FullPath) показывает уже новый полный путь к файлу:

```
// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{        
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется это невозможно. Почему файл обязательно откуда-то скопирован? Он может быть просто создан.

Comment: @Zergatul, в случае просто создания можно гипотетичному свойству OldFullPath присваивать String.Empty, например.

Comment: невозможно. Файл может быть создан, скопирован (фактически создан новый), перенесен, получен из сети(фактически создан новый, но с доп атрибутами) и т.д. Система это почти не отслеживает, максимум можно отменить последнюю операцию и то не всегда.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher обертка над очень низкоуровневым WinAPI. Копированием файлов занимается высокоуровневый код. В данном случае FileSystemWatcher ничего не может знать о том, как этот файл появился.

Comment: чисто теоретически, можно включить аудит файловой системы и ловить сообщения в логе вместо вотчера, только такой аудит довольно тяжеловесная штука и кроме системных тормозов получите еще и периодическое переполнение журналов аудита, так что на практике применять не стоит, я пробовал.

Comment: Представьте себе, что вы пишете процедуру копирования. Вы заводите буфер, открываете файл, читаете, пишете в целевой файл, снова читаете полный буфер, снова пишете в целевой файл, и так до исчерпания исходного файла. После этого, когда копирование завершено, вы удаляете исходный файл. Внимание, вопрос: откуда система может знать, каков источник данных для вашего нового файла?